# ASP.NET Context RewritePath 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-status-code-404

I have an .net 4.0 web application works like a charm at my local computer and old web server. Both computer uses classic and .net 4.0 application pool without any problems.

But when i migrated to a new web server it gives 404 error instead of rewriting urls.
I created a new application as simple as it can be. It rewrites all request paths to default.aspx as seen as below:

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.RewritePath("default.aspx", false);
}
```

I can access default.aspx if i make a direct request to file itself but when i make a request to an adress except 'default.aspx' i get 404 error from static file handler.

Do you have any idea, how can i fix it?

Fullsize image [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arBhX.png)
[image]

Comment: its look like the `ahmet` is not pass from asp.net and for that reason and the RewritePath is not working.

Comment: Yep RewritePath is not working and that's why i'm asking how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check application pool identity settings. Make sure your web application's appPool Identity is set ApplicationPoolIdentity and Managed Pipeline Mode should be Integrated.

Then check your web config system.webserver modules and enable this configuration on your application web config.

```
<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> </modules></system.webServer>
```

Comment: Managed pipeline mode cannot be Integrated because we have a load of classic ASP that need to run in classic mode.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue. I have a URL rewriting class in the APP_Code folder that worked running on Visual Studio 2008 development server and IIS 6.5 but **not** in IIS 7.5. The "OnBeginRequest" appeared not to fire and I was receiving the same 404 error. After quite a bit of trial and error I found the combination which solved my issue:

In IIS 7.5 under the website basic settings, changed the application pool setting to "Classic .NET AppPool".

In Web.config, I added the following to reference the URL Rewriting class:

```
<httpModules>
     <add name="*URLRewriteClassName*" type="*Namespace.URLRewriteClassName*"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Since you are executing your rewrite code from the Global Application Class I would try changing the application pool first and see what happens. Hopefully this helps and good luck!